# How to run R script with gdb attached?

Tags: debugging, r, gdb

I have an R script that's usually started from the command line with arguments:

```
./script.R --width=10
```

It uses Rscript as interpreter:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
```

Unfortunately it gives me a segmentation fault when it executes my compiled C code in R using `.C("compiled_function")`.

So how can I run my `R` script with the `gdb` debugger attached?

`Rscript` apparently does not know the `-d` option.

I tried this

```
R -d gdb --vanilla --args --width=10 < script.R
```

But it didn't work since it passed the `--width=10` to the debugger. What is the right call?

Maybe I should start `R` interactively:

```
$ R -d gdb --vanilla
```

But then I don't know how to `source` my script and pass the arguments (`--width=10`).

Answer (score 6):

I think a general GNU getopt convention is to use `--` to denote *remaining arguments*. So try

```
 R -d gdb --vanilla -- --width=10 < script.R
```

Else hardwire the argument value in your script or compiled function.

Comment: When I try that, for some reason, the R code in script.R is interpreted by gdb, which is a mess. There must be a way to call this thing without hardwiring the argument values in my script (I have actually quite many arguments, not just the one I gave in the example).

Comment: Then don't use redirect. Fire up `R -d gdb` and do `source("script.R")` instead.

Comment: But how can I pass the options to the script, then? If I just say `source("script.R")` it will complain that the values ("width", etc.) are not set.

Comment: Maybe set them at the very top?